# Responsive difference between mobile view display vs browser view, even though same size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand how response works. I have content meta viewport tags full initial scale like regular so no problem there.

Here's what I don't understand, I explained to chat GPT:

ok I understand the problem, on mobile display, even though screen size is 320 and page content is more than 320 it fits the whole page in full screen scaling accordingly thus no scrollbar appears. on browser view only screen size of content is shown rest of the page content is overflow out with scrollbars

but what controls the mobile view to fit the whole page content in the display area where in browser it only shows as much as viewport area and show scrollbars

I am talking about chrome developer tools, mobile display and browser view, even though they have the same viewport size, mobile display fits the whole page content on the screen scaling accordingly, while the browser view only displays as much as viewport size displaying scrollbars for the rest of the page content to appear.

Comment: https://chat.openai.com/share/5335cbcf-ef21-4538-84a7-acb888350cfd