# Position fixed bottom: 0, goes to the bottom of the page instead bottom of the screen

Tags: html, css

### EDit

I have found out that the issue is related to my previous question here:
[Responsive difference between mobile view display vs browser view, even though same size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78043938/responsive-difference-between-mobile-view-display-vs-browser-view-even-though-s)

So it works as expected in regular desktop view.
But when I switch on devtools and mobile view, Chrome acts buggy. Something about an overflow behavior, like I described on that question. Like I don't even know how responsiveness supposed to be implemented.

### Original

I have something like this:

```
<div class='root'>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <span>Hello</span>
      <span>World</span>
      <span>Fixed</span>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class='main'>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.main {
  height: 2000px;
}

header {
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

nav span {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

I've setup this on codepen, and the nav element with position fixed bottom: 0, extends up to the height of the screen area.

But in my real example the same setup, the nav element extends the the bottom of the page content which in this case '.main' which has a height of 2000px or something.

I can't figure out any other difference I have, maybe some media query issue I don't know.

So could you find a simple solution to reproduce my issue that somehow make it that this nav element extends to the bottom of the page, what could be causing that?

Comment: did you mean position absolute?

Comment: no fixed, i am building a navigation bar for mobile.

Comment: But if it's fixed and goes to the bottom of the document body not the visible window height then any content beyond the window height will never be reachable, because it's fixed, i.e. never scrolls.

Comment: No it acts like part of the page it has the same height as the body and scrolls with the page. I could post a video here. 
I produced it like there is this chess site lichess.org, I opened it on chrome devtools, and started copying the styles. It's all wrapped in media queries, maybe there is a chrome bug or something.

Comment: even if it was position absolute, header has position relative and it is 60px height at the top of the page. I also changed position: fixed, to position: absolute, now nav doesn't display at all, just covers 60px area.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see how we can help given that the code presented works as expected (the fixed element covering the height of the viewport). What exactly do you see as the applied CSS when you inspect that element?

Comment: You probably have one of the properties applied to an ancestor element, that changes what constitutes the containing block - see 4. here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#identifying_the_containing_block

Comment: *"No it acts like part of the page it has the same height as the body and scrolls with the page"* Like I said: it should be `position: absolute;` Fixed does not scroll. It not displaying as you want it to when it's absolute is the problem you are looking to solve.